# How to pick date in any format from a string in node JS?

Tags: node.js

I have a string like this :

Date/Time : November 28, 2016 09:19:52A - NC4-105-01-32

How can i parse this to get the date alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a date object from the question.  The easiest way is with `substr` [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and `new Date()` [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```

```js
const dateString = 'Date/Time: November 28, 2016 09:19:52A - NC4-105-01-32'

const dateObject = new Date(dateString.substr(11, 17));

console.log(dateObject)
```

```

Comment: Can we use regex function for this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, use regex for what?

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always that way, then you can parse it like this.

```
var start = string.indexOf(':') + 1;
var end = string.indexOf(',', start) + 5;
var date = new Date(string.substr(start, end).trim());
```